# Search for a specific Outlook email

Tags: vba, outlook

What Visual Basic for Applications method will allow me to find a specific Outlook email so that I can access data from it like its message content - perhaps by searching by the subject of the email?

Comment: `Items.Restrict`

Answer (score 0):

Items.Find Method is a alternative solution, you can use VBA string search function:

```
Sub sofWorkWithOutlook20082550()
  Dim outlookApp
  Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
  Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
  Dim olMail As Variant
  Dim myTasks
  Dim sir() As String

  'Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
  Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

  Set olNs = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

  '
  'Set olMail = myTasks.Find("[Subject] = ""123456""")
  '
  For Each olMail In myTasks
  '
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "My-Text-to-Search", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
      olMail.Display
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

PS: change "My-Text-to-Search" to some string you have in your email
Acess this site for more information: [Items.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662.aspx)